# Как подключить тему для bootstrap?

Tags: themes, веб-программирование, bootstrap, css, less

Есть сайт с темами для `bootstrap` bootswatch.com, там можно скачать темы в виде файла bootstrap.min.css. Вопрос: как подключить эту тему? Просто заменить обычный bootstrap.min.css на этот файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Есть сайт с темами для bootstrap
> bootswatch.com там можно скачать темы
> в виде файла bootstrap.min.css.

На упомянутом Вами ресурсе бесплатные темы отличаются только файлами стилей. Следовательно, Вы все делаете правильно.

Однако Bootstrap - это не только CSS фреймворк, немаловажную роль играют его компоненты. Думаю, Вас заинтересуют [более комплексные темы](http://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/all/).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.